# How can I retrieve more than 25 pages from the Stack Exchange API v2.3?

Tags: support, api-key, paging

I'm trying to find a way to retrieve all the results from a search query from the Stack Exchange API v2.3. My use case includes more than 25 pages (I already use the maximum page size of 100).

The documentation says that the [maximum page number for anonymous API access is 25](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs).

I have already registered my app and I used my key in the request. Still, I cannot retrieve more than 25 pages.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply using an API key is enough to [increase your quota from 300 to 10,000 per day](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle), but it does not qualify as non-anonymous access.

> The maximum page number that will be returned for anonymous API access (no auth token) is 25

The 'auth token' this sentence is referring to is obtained via [authentication](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication), and registering your app is only the first step.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am still not sure about the difference between access tokens and keys. I thought that access tokens are used for writing purposes and that every individual user has to allow my application to access information. Since I want to retrieve, for example, a list of users with a get request, getting permission from every user is not possible. Is an access token still the right thing to use and how is it used? The documentation didn't really answer my question.

Comment: Access tokens are also used to *read* personal information (e.g. your inbox). And (and this is rather new) to get extended pagination. You do not have to get permission from all users; you just need to authenticate yourself. This can be done with command line tools - see [this Q&A I just wrote](https://stackapps.com/q/9345/34061).