# How can I quickly get an access token for personal use?

Tags: support, api, oauth2, authentication

Registering your application or script gets you a [higher daily quota](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle) and is fairly simply; a step by step guide is documented here: [I only need a key, what do I do?](https://stackapps.com/q/8971/34061)

However, what if I do want an access token, either to get around the new [paging restrictions for anonymous users](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/), to read personal information (e.g. my inbox) or to get write access? Do I have to set up a website so I can use the OAuth flow as described in the [documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's possible to authenticate yourself via the command line; there's no need to set up a website or so.

- Open the application page via https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth and make sure the option 'Enable Client Side OAuth Flow' is disabled.

  - You can use any domain (e.g. `stackapps.com`) as OAuth domain; you don't need to control it.
- Open the following URL in your browser (add the actual client id from the application page, and the scope with what you actually need - for details, see the [documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication#scope)): `https://stackoverflow.com/oauth?client_id=...&scope=read_inbox,no_expiry,write_access,private_info&redirect_uri=https://stackapps.com`
- After authenticating, you'll get redirected to `https://stackapps.com/?code=...`; the code ends in `))`.
- Execute the following command in a terminal (add the client id and client secret from the application page and the code from the previous step): `curl -d "client_id=...&client_secret=...&code=...&redirect_uri=https://stackapps.com" -X POST https://stackoverflow.com/oauth/access_token`
- The result is a simple `access_token=...` and the token also ends in `))`.

You can now [use that token in combination with your app key](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication#usage), e.g. to [read your global inbox](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/inbox) with a GET call to `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/inbox?key=...&access_token=...`.

Another option is provided [here](https://stackapps.com/q/9181/34061) by @rene, but this one is (IMVHO, of course) simpler if you know how to handle the command line and/or you're not particularly fond of JavaScript.

Comment: I was wondering if the *... ends with ))* is a feature or a coincidence with the chosen encoding. IOW, do we risk ever seeing a token that doesn't end in `))` when we exhausted all the space the token allows for? (probably in 6 to 8 weeks)

Comment: I have no idea. I thought it was some Base64 dialect I didn't know of, but some investigation did not get me any wiser ...

Comment: [Maybe ASCII85](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31828482) ....