# How to apply an access token in order to scrape the recommended answers?

Tags: support, app, oauth2, write-access

I'm trying to scrape some data which needs the access token, and I received

> 'Applications must have a registered Stack Apps post to write'

Does that mean I need to post a question on Stack Exchange so that I can use this access token? When I paste the access token url in the field Stack Apps Post (optional).  It said that 'Post must be on Stack Apps'. I don't know how to do.
Anyone to help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Apps! I'm not sure why you'd need *write* access for scraping, but you might be helped with the FAQs we recently wrote: [I only need a key, what do I do?](https://stackapps.com/q/8971/34061) and [How can I quickly get an access token for personal use?](https://stackapps.com/q/9345/34061)

Comment: Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](//stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE) on Stack Overflow. While there isn't an explicit requirement on Stack Apps for an MRE, the reason for the requirement on Stack Overflow is that debugging questions normally aren't answerable without such an example. While your titular question of "how to" wouldn't normally need a MRE, it actually devolves to a debugging question, because your titular question and the issues you describe in the question text, don't make sense (i.e. you don't need write access to *read*).

Comment: Access token is needed for some field which are considered private to the user or stack exchange community. So show which particular request you want to do with which query. Authorisation token can be retrieve using method described in api documentation.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to scrape, I would limit the `scope` you request. These are the options mentioned in [Authetnication](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication):

- read_inbox - access a user's global inbox
- no_expiry - access_token's with this scope do not expire
- write_access - perform write operations as a user
- private_info - access full history of a user's private actions on the site

When you include `write_access` in the OAuth call for the scope parameter in either `https://stackoverflow.com/oauth?scope=` or `https://stackoverflow.com/oauth/dialog` your App registration needs to have a public, non-deleted question on Stack Apps.

When you edit your Registered App you set the field here:

[image: Stack App Post (optional) input box]

In your specific case you can enter `https://stackapps.com/questions/9490` in the *Stack Apps Post* fields, if you insist on requesting `write_access` when authenticating.

Don't forget to click *Submit Changes* to save your changes to your Registered App.